# Javascript array returns only single character

Tags: javascript, json

Okay, this is my first question on stack overflow, i hope to do it correctly.
I'm actually working on a function that takes the values of some var that i have saved in an array in a cookie.
As you can see i tried like, anything i can but it doesn't work correctly.
The var p1, for example if the array is [20,1000,1,0,0], returns the number 2 instead of 20.
It's like it doesn't treat the var stringfy as an array.
Sorry for the mess, hope you can help.

```
function getCookie() {
"use strict";
var value = "; " + document.cookie;
alert (value);              // this returns ; ciccio=[20,1000,1,0,0]
var ciccio = "ciccio";      // the name of the cookie to split it  
var parts = value.split("; " +ciccio+ "=");
var arr = parts.pop().split(";").shift();
alert (arr);                // this returns [20,1000,1,0,0]
var arr1 = arr.slice(1, -1);
alert(arr1);                // this returns 20,1000,1,0,0
var stringfy = JSON.stringify(arr); 
alert (stringfy);           // this returns "20,1000,1,0,0
var p1 = parseInt(stringfy[1]);
alert (p1);                 // this returns 2
p = p1;
document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = p;

}
```

P.s it doesn't work even without the json stringfy or without the arr.slice, i was just trying all that came in my mind.

Comment: call `JSON.parse(arr)` then you will have an actual array

Comment: *Stringify* means **Turn into a string**, so "Yes, obviously it is a string. You explicitly asked for it to be one".

Answer (score 2):

You are not getting what you think you are getting.  You have a string from the start and, after that, when you call `JSON.stringify()`, you are doing that to a string, **which gives you a second set of quotes in that string**.  Then when you use `stringify[1]`, you are attempting to get the second character from that string.

See comments in code below for actual values you have.

```js
var value = "; ciccio=[20,1000,1,0,0]"; // simulated cookie value
console.log(value);
var ciccio = "ciccio";      // the name of the cookie to split it  
var parts = value.split("; " + ciccio + "=");

// No need for pop and shift. Just drop the first part and use the second
var arr = parts[1];

console.log(arr);                // this returns "[20,1000,1,0,0]" <-- STRING
var arr1 = arr.slice(1, -1);
console.log(arr1);                // this returns "20,1000,1,0,0" <-- STRING

// You still have an array. This is what you should be passing your
// index to in order to get parts of the cookie data out:
console.log(arr1[1]);

// This will take your string and stringify it again!
var stringfy = JSON.stringify(arr); 
console.log(stringfy);           // this returns '"[20,1000,1,0,0]"' <-- STRING with quotes in it

// This line converts the second character in the string to an integer and returns it
var p1 = parseInt(stringfy[1], 10);
console.log(p1);                 // this returns NaN, not 2!
```

Getting the cookie string as an array is much easier than you are doing:

```js
var value = "; ciccio=[20,1000,1,0,0]"; // simulated cookie value
console.log(value);
 
// Create an array of 2 elements: ["; ciccio=", "[20,1000,1,0,0]"]
var parts = value.split("; ciccio=");

// Turn second array element (a string) into array of its own:
var ary = JSON.parse(parts[1]);

// Access array as normal
console.log(ary[1]);
```

Comment: What you are looking for in p1 you have at arr1[0]

Comment: `arr1 == "20,1000,1,0,0"` so `arr1[1] == "0"` at no point are they actually creating an array, it's always a string. They do have a valid _array string_ with the value `arr` so they can do `var arr1 = JSON.parse(arr);` and then `arr1[1]` to get `1000`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your *array* in the fact that it never actually is an array. It's always a string, even before you `JSON.stringify()` it.

You can convert it to a *actual* array at the point where your have the value `arr` with the use of `JSON.parse()`

```js
var value = "; " + "ciccio=[20,1000,1,0,0]"
console.log(value);
var ciccio = "ciccio"; // the name of the cookie to split it  
var parts = value.split("; " + ciccio + "=");
var arr = parts.pop().split(";").shift();
console.log(arr)
var arr1 = JSON.parse(arr);
console.log(arr1[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.cookie` is a string, so you need to parse it in order to convert it to array.

If you want the `ciccio` value, you can use regExp like this:

```
var ciccioMatches = document.cookie.match(/ciccio=([^;]+);/)

console.log(ciccioMatches); // ['ciccio=[....]', '[....]']
```

The second result will be the serialized array, so you need to `JSON.parse` it to get it as an actual array:

```
var ciccio = JSON.parse(ciccionMatches[1]);
```

No need to say that you need to check that there are some matches before actually parsing the first index of the `ciccionMatches` array

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

Here you go :

```
let obj ="[20,1000,1,0,0]";
let newObj = JSON.parse(obj);

console.log(newObj[0]); //return 20
```

https://jsfiddle.net/emilvr/a1uzjf3o/